# how to insert empty default option to top of dropdown without triggering validation error?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm using Angular 2 and I'm implementing a dropdown. The first default item in the dropdown should be empty because the system has no logic for inferring the default choice of the user.  The user is required to select a value from this dropdown so the dropdown uses standard required field validation for Angular 2 forms like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="report">Report Type</label>
   <select class="form-control" required
     [(ngModel)]="model.reportType"
       name="reportType" #reportType="ngModel" >
     <option *ngFor="let r of reportTypes" [value]="r">{{r}}</option>
   </select>
   <div [hidden]="reportType.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
     Report Type is required
   </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that when the page is initialized with the empty default dropdown item selected, the required field validation gets triggered and displayed. I'm sure there's a structured way to handle this use case in Angular 2 forms since this is a fairly common use case.  Can you suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changed your error div to:

```
<div [hidden]="reportType.pristine || reportType.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
  Report Type is required
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Harry.  That hides the div that displays the message but the red marker on the left vertical line of the dropdown still displays.  Do you know what I can update to suppress the red validation marker when the form is pristine?

Comment: Hey that's something related to CSS. Would you be able to provide the CSS rule that style red strip for error message there? I believe most of the time the CSS selector includes ".ng-invalid". In that case, you'd need to change it to ".ng-invalid.ng-touched".

Comment: Thanks Harry. Looks like your evaluation was spot on. The class for the output select should have ng-touched instead of ng-untouched. However, I'm not sure where I can make this update. The select input has a class of "form-control" and attribute of required in my markup.  However, the rendered class for the input is:

class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"

Any idea how I can change my markup to output the update you recommended?

Comment: The <select> markup has a class of "form-control" so I'm guessing that the additional classes that are output "ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" are generated from the Angular implementation context when the Angular f/w sees the <select> input marked with the "required" attribute. Does this seem to be a correct assumption?

Comment: Hey, form-group has nothing to do with it. Angular is responsible in changing these classes. Basically when you didn't touch anything it will be 'pristine' and 'untouched', once you select or key in something the state changes to 'touched'. The idea is you only care to display error to those inputs that have been touched and invalid. What I suggested was updating CSS to reflect that, not update the markup itself.